# roslaunch if/unless for non-boolean arguments

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make a launch file which checks an argument value (string) and loads parameters accordingly. I don't seem to find any documentation regarding this, the if/unless attributes section in the [roslaunch wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) only works with booleans. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<arg name="mode"                 default="mode_a"/> <!-- mode_a, mode_b, mode_c... -->

<node pkg="node" type="node_type" name="node_name" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find test)/config/mode_a_params.yaml" if="$(arg mode)"=="mode_a" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find test)/config/mode_d_params.yaml" unless="$(arg mode)"=="mode_b" />
</node>
```

But since if/unless work only with booleans, this is not possible. The following code shows my work-around. I made two new flag arguments (boolean), but the issue here is that I need to set the flags every time I change the mode.

```
<arg name="mode"                 default="mode_a"/> <!-- mode_a, mode_b, mode_c... -->
<arg name="mode_a_flag"      default="true"/> <!-- set to true if mode = mode_a, else false -->
<arg name="mode_c_flag"      default="false"/> <!-- set to true if mode = mode_c, else false -->

<node pkg="node" type="node_type" name="node_name" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find test)/config/mode_a_params.yaml" if="$(arg mode_a_flag)" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find test)/config/mode_d_params.yaml" unless="$(arg mode_c_flag)" />
</node>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm looking for a way where I just need to set the mode when launching the file and the flags are set automatically in the launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385696/roslaunch-if/unless-for-non-boolean-arguments/) by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2021-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this using `eval` which evaluates an expression and returns a boolean. Eg, in your case you can do

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find test)/config/mode_a_params.yaml" if="$(eval arg('mode') == 'mode_a')" />
```

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2021-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on 2021-09-03**:
This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!